# How to make accordion to expand on hover not on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion

Is it possible to make accordion to expand on hover not on click? And how to do something else on click?

**UPDATE**

I was speaking about jQuery UI accordion widget.

Comment: Of course. Now what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to ask this site another way and I was told it is possible only in HTML5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557955/how-to-make-accordion-sections-both-selectors-and-hyperlinks/11558085#11558085    How great that I finally reach such an obvious version of a question that you started to put minuses to me. THANK YOU GUYS!

Comment: @SuzanCioc obvious or not, we can help you with specific programming problems. Not "how do i do this"

Comment: I think stackoverflow is dying. The same question is treated either as mystery or bullshit. Site is becoming useless.

Comment: @SuzanCioc This is not a good question please try to explain what you have tried what you want to do. When you talk about accordions and jQuery I atleast instally think of: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ Please post code and fix tags if needed.

Comment: @sachleen you are not helping me. You can't, unable helping. You either don't know the answer or putting minuses. Nothing third.

Comment: @SuzanCioc This isn't even the same question as the other one...

Comment: @Andreas, I explained everything in previous version of a question. Where you were with your important advices?

Comment: @SuzanCioc I think you need to calm down a little. I recommend putting something on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can play with. Tell us what it does currently, what you want it to do, and what you've tried to make that happen.

Comment: sachleen, this is the same problem. When I were there, nobody knew an answer, but when I came to solution myself, everybody appeared to be clever enough to advice me :D

Comment: Have you tried setting the accordion to open on hover and then bind click events to your headers? You didn't post any code or anything, so we don't know what you've tried.

Comment: @MrOBrian I was not trying this since was told this is unlikely possible by previous question. Now I was transparently "hinted" that this is possible by hover, and will do that.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Calm down. Your two questions have nothing to do with each other, this seems obvious to me. **If** SO is dying, it is dying because of angry and lazy people. I will vote to close because this question shows absolutely no research effort. At least try to read the documentation, the 5. example is just what you're talking about... And don't attack people who are trying to point out your mistakes.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I do not need my apparent mistakes pointed, I just need an answer. Initially SO was a site where it was possible to find that answers. To find out about self imperfection were all other web sites for. Now SO is becoming similar to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[5th example in the jQuery UI Accordion documentation: Open on mouseover](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover)

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    event: "mouseover"
});
```

You can attach any click events you wish to using the `.click()` or `.on('click')` methods in plain jQuery. Please research before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS accordion: http://jsbin.com/atamat/edit#html,live

```
.accordion > div {
    display: none;
}

.accordion:hover > div {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h2><a href="#link2">Header goes here</a></h2>
    <div>
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <h2><a href="#link2">Header goes here</a></h2>
    <div>
        Content goes here<br/>Content goes here<br/>Content goes here<br/>
        Content goes here<br/>Content goes here<br/>Content goes here<br/>
        Content goes here<br/>Content goes here<br/>Content goes here<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simple jQuery solution: http://jsbin.com/atamat/2/edit#javascript,html,live

```
$(".accordion > div").hide().parent().hover(function(event) {
  $(this).children("div").slideToggle(event.type === "mouseenter");
});
```

HTML:

> The same ^